# mySQL IF statement syntax

Tags: mysql, if-statement

This is MySQL and it complains about if statement. Maybe anyone sees the mistake, because I think I looked at it too long:

```
SELECT c.id AS id, (p.validFor * 30) AS validFor, p.validFrom as validFrom, 
date(FROM_UNIXTIME(rr.timemodified)) as date, 
( CASE 
    WHEN date(validFrom) < date(FROM_UNIXTIME(rr.timemodified)) THEN (DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(rr.timemodified), INTERVAL p.validFor MONTH) , NOW())) 
    WHEN date(validFrom) > date(FROM_UNIXTIME(rr.timemodified)) THEN (DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(validFrom, INTERVAL p.validFor MONTH) , NOW()) ) 
END )AS daysLeft, 
IF (rr.timemodified < g.timemodified, (DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(g.timemodified), INTERVAL p.validFor MONTH) , NOW())- (validFor * 30.48))) as daysLeft

FROM mdl_readtickbox_responses rr 
JOIN mdl_readtickbox r ON r.id = rr.readtickboxid 
JOIN mdl_course c ON c.id = r.course 
JOIN mdl_procedures p ON p.id = c.idnumber 
JOIN mdl_groups_members gm ON gm.userid = rr.userid 
JOIN mdl_groups g ON g.id = gm.groupid 
WHERE rr.userid = '2' 
AND g.courseid = r.course 
AND p.status != 'obsolete' 
ORDER BY p.priority, daysLeft
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot the else in if statment

```
 IF (rr.timemodified < g.timemodified, (DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(g.timemodified), INTERVAL p.validFor MONTH) , NOW())- (validFor * 30.48)), *********) as daysLeft
                                                                                                                                                    --->>>>> write your else conditon here
```

Comment: Thank you :) Totally forgot :)

Comment: you welcome :) ! if it solved your question make sure to accept answer as solved

Answer (score 0):

You dont have a `FALSE` part

```
IF (
        rr.timemodified < g.timemodified, 
        (DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(g.timemodified), INTERVAL p.validFor MONTH) , NOW())- (validFor * 30.48))
    ) as daysLeft
```

[IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

> If expr1 is TRUE (expr1 <> 0 and expr1 <> NULL) then IF() returns
>   expr2; otherwise it returns expr3.